# Java how to skipping holiday in maintenance scheduling?

Tags: optaplanner

Skip weekends. Does not work for holidays.
To skip holidays too, cache all working days in scoreDirector.getWorkingSolution().getWorkCalendar().
Keep in sync with Programme.createStartDateList().

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from optaplanner-quickstarts's maintenance scheduling example:

- First precalculate (before calling `solve()`) all working days and store them in a `List<LocalDate>` in `WorkCalendar`.
- In `MaintenanceSchedule.createStartDateList()` return that list as the planning value range.
- In `EndDateUpdatingVariableListener.calculateEndDate()` use that list instead of presuming it all weekdays (including holidays) are workdays.